# Load Testing Azure Web App with OAuth2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service, load-testing, azure-devops

I'm trying to wrap my brain around setting up load testing secure azure web applications. I want to push a load test to the cloud, which is pretty simple given we are using VS online. However, when running multiple users I get several errors. I think the errors revolve around a single account trying to gain authorization to web app simulated with multiple 'virtual users.'

**Errors:** https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login----{POST} Context parameter $HIDDEN1.ctx not found in test context

https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/----{POST} Context parameter $HIDDEN1.code not found in test context

**a slew of socket exceptions:**
https://localhost:port/skypetoc/v1/pnr/parse----{POST} connection actively refused

**ValidateResponseUrl errors**
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/----{GET} The value of the expectedresponseUrl property 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize does not equal the actual response url https://mysite.azurewebsites.net querystring parameters were ignored.

running this test locally with a single user account works fine. pushing to the cloud under a single login account with multiple simulated users yields all these errors.

**Questions**:
**1.** Do I need to create n number of user accounts for this to work properly?
**2.** Do I just need to create custom plugins at the request level to get new auth tokens per user request?
**3.** Is there any built in support for this kind of stuff in Visual Studio Online Azure load testing?

I really don't want to test the performance of login since its out of my hands. but I do want to test the performance of my web app under load for other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Online does not allow localhost to be the hostname in your callback URL. You can edit the hosts file on your local computer to map a hostname to 127.0.0.1. Then use this hostname when you register your app. Or, you can deploy your app when testing to a Microsoft Azure website to be able to debug and use HTTPS for the callback URL. See: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started-auth-oauth2-vsi.aspx